# Readng an array of structures from file

Tags: python, struct

I have the next task: I need to read an array of structures from file.
There is no problem to read one structure:

```
structFmt = "=64s 2L 3d"    # char[ 64 ] long[ 2 ] double [ 3 ]
structLen = struct.calcsize( structFmt )
f = open( "path/to/file", "rb" )
structBytes = f.read( structLen )
s = struct.unpack( structFmt, structBytes )
```

Also there is no problem to read an array of "simple" types:

```
f = open( "path/to/file", "rb" )
a = array.array( 'i' )
a.fromfile( f, 1024 )
```

But there is a problem (for me, of course) to read 1024 structures `structFmt` from file.
I think, that it is an overhead to read 1024 times struct and append it to a list.
I do not want to use external dependencies like `numpy`.

Comment: To know what the bottleneck really is, you need to profile your code and see what it's spending its time doing.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at mmaping the file and then using ctypes class method from_buffer() call.
This will map the ctypes defined array of structs http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes#ctypes-arrays.

This maps the structs over the mmap file without having to explicitly read/convert and copy things.

I don't know if the end result will be appropriate though.

Just for fun here is a quick example using mmap.  (I created a file using dd `dd if=/dev/zero of=./test.dat bs=96 count=10240`

```
from ctypes import Structure
from ctypes import c_char, c_long, c_double
import mmap
import timeit


class StructFMT(Structure):
     _fields_ = [('ch',c_char * 64),('lo',c_long *2),('db',c_double * 3)]

d_array = StructFMT * 1024

def doit():
    f = open('test.dat','r+b')
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
    data = d_array.from_buffer(m)

    for i in data:
        i.ch, i.lo[0]*10 ,i.db[2]*1.0   # just access each row and bit of the struct and do something, with the data.

    m.close()
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("doit()", "from __main__ import doit")
    print t.timeit(number=10)
```

Comment: What's the point of using `mmap`, couldn't one just read the entire array into a memory buffer and apply `from_buffer()` to that?

Comment: you could do that.  With mmap however files are directly paged into memory on demand.  So for instance if you access the last part of the array you won't have had to read all of the preceding contents into memory first and then use from_buffer().

Comment: If you have a large file to mmap and you only sparsely access part of the structure then this could be a big win. If you read/copy every bit of the file then their probably isn't.  Though I/O performance could give mmap an edge. That would need to benchmarked of course.

Comment: Well, for an 84K array `mmap` seems like a bit of overkill -- but the ctypes structure + `from_buffer()` combo seems like a very efficient way to read them all in with a minimal amount of processing. The fact that it also lends itself to `mmap`ing is a nice feature even it's not needed here. +1

Comment: people often forget about mmap, it's particularly useful if you are dealing with files significantly bigger than memory and you don't need to copy data around (ie read, do something and forget).

Comment: After hours of googleing and trying different variants I choosed the following one :

    samplesBytes = f.read()
    samplesCount = len( samplesBytes ) / sizeof( Ipp16sc )
    samples = (Ipp16sc * samplesCount)()
    memmove( pointer( samples ), samplesBytes, len( samplesBytes ) );

Could you tell me, is it the best way ? Thank to @TimHoffman

Comment: @borisbn: Answer your own question with the code in your comment if you want it critiqued.

Comment: @martineau: I thought, that 1) this is not an answer, but just 'thinking out loud'... and 2) it would show code correctly, if I indent it by four spaces....

Comment: @TimHoffman: thank you for code (I'll try it), but I have not so easy format of file: there is one big header and a chain of a little structs (very similar to WAVE-file format). Is there a way to use mmap with this format ?

Comment: Would need to see the exact format.  If it's all fixed sizes and not based on lengths encoded in other structures then very easy.  Even the other stuff could be done too.  Just depends if its worth the effort ;-)

Comment: The format is: the fixed length header (110 bytes length) followed by array of comlex (real and imagine) 'shorts' (16 bits signed integer). Here is my decision. Could you comment it, please - http://pastebin.com/zsJUTx0K

Comment: Do you get expected results ?  I don't have your data, so only you can say it is correct.  One question, why do you do the from_buffer_copy? That effectively means you end up copying the data and it appears from your code that would be an unnecessary processing and memory overhead.  Try running it again to compare with just a from_buffer.

Comment: Yes, I did (got the result, that I waited for). I used from_buffer_copy because of following error "Cannot use string as modifiable buffer" while trying from_buffer. I got this error when I pass m[:headerLen] to that func. instead of m itself. When I tried to mmap a part of file (giving an offset) I got the following error:  "WindowsError: [Error 1132]". In fact, I solved the problem (except of _copy). Thanks 2 all.

Comment: AHH, your on windows.  mmap has different semantics, also if you are modifying values in the mmap'd file then you would need to set ACCESS_WRITE for the access parameter in the mmap constructor. That might negate the need for the copy. Again worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, there is no analog for *array* that holds complex structs.

The usual technique is to make many calls to struct.unpack and append the results to a list.

```
structFmt = "=64s 2L 3d"    # char[ 64 ] long[ 2 ] double [ 3 ]
structLen = struct.calcsize( structFmt )
results = []
with open( "path/to/file", "rb" ) as f:
    structBytes = f.read( structLen )
    s = struct.unpack( structFmt, structBytes )
    results.append(s)
```

If you're concerned about being efficient, know that *struct.unpack* caches the parsed structure between successive calls.

Comment: Thank to @RaymondHettinger. I'll compare my decision (in comment to prev. answer) and yours one by their times. BTW, how to count function's execution time ?

Comment: I tested mmap variant vs struct.unpack. The first one is about 100 times (113 to be exact) faster.

Comment: @borisbn: You have to be very careful when comparing this method to one based on mmap because the latter doesn't read structures in the file unless you access them. A good comparison would access all of them.

Comment: @martineau: hmmm. You're absolutely right. In first test I accessed first 8192 elements of array. Now I tried to access all elements and... the result is: 63 seconds for mmap and 86 seconds for single read and unpack (plus access to elements in both tests). Here is the whole test - http://pastebin.com/mr5nReG7. Could you comment it, please ? Thank you.

Comment: @borisbn: I think you should change the `samples = s.from_buffer_copy( m[headerLen:] )` line in your test to `samples = s.from_buffer( m, headerLen )` because otherwise you're reading in a copy of almost the whole file into memory with it which defeats one of the possible advantages of mmap. I also suggest you take a look at the Wikipedia article on the general idea of [memory-mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: @Raymond Hettinger: Would it not be possible to create a long `stuctFmt` representing the entire array of structures by multiplying the single structure format N times and then unpack all the data in one call (assuming you knew how many there were in advance)?

Comment: @martineau Yes, that would work, but first make sure that unpacking is the bottleneck.  Most scripts like this are IO bound.  Also, doing any work with the result list is likely to take more time than the unpacking.

Comment: @Raymond Hettinger: Good points, but being able to unpack a large number of structs all at once means you could read an equally large number of them in at a time beforehand, thereby reducing some disk I/O overhead, too.

Comment: @borisbn: Also, after reading comments you made to the other answer, in addition to changing the `from_buffer_copy()` to `from_buffer()`, I suggest you also change the call to the mmap constructor to `m = mmap.mmap( f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ )` because you have opened the file for read-only but the default for mmap on Windows is for a write-through mapping.