# Cython - Optimize read binary file

Tags: python, file, binary, cython

I am trying to improve this cython code (which works). Please note that I don't want to use numpy.fromfile.. because I want to be able to parse not fixed binary structures.

```
from libc.stdio cimport *  
import struct


cpdef inline cimport_td(char* f, double[:] dates, double[:] tpx, int[:] tvo):
    f_b = open(f.replace('\\','/'),'rb').read()

    cdef int B = len(f_b), bb = 0, dd = 0
    while bb < B:   
        dates[dd], tpx[dd], tvo[dd] = struct.unpack('ddi', f_b[bb:bb+20])      
        bb += 20
        dd += 1

    del f_b
    return dates, tpx, tvo
```

Is there anything better than open/read and struct unpack ?

Thank you.

Comment: "Better" in what sense? To put it another way, what do you feel is wrong with this sample?

Comment: Is it too slow? Someone smarter than you said ["...premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Yes, sorry I want to optimize the execution time. I especially want to know if there is a way of using C libraries instead of struct and open and read. Because stdio is not used in this piece of code.

Comment: I don't know how it relates to Cython, but perhaps you could do something similar to what's in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11859345/355230) which uses the `ctypes.Structure` subclass (ignoring the part about using `mmap` in conjunction with the class method `from_buffer()`).

Comment: Do you still care about this? If so, would you mind some C++ usage?